# apply a change of variable to an expression

Tags: algebra

What would be the simplest way in which we can write

`y[x1_, x2_, x3_] = x1 + x2*x3`

then
`x4 = x2*x3;`

to get to the form:

`y[x1_,x4_] = x1 + x4`

**Context**: I'm trying to write the result of a `FullSimplified` expression

$$e_{1,\text{eq}}\left(\tau _{e,1}, \tau _{e,2}, \tau _{a,2}, \tau _{a,1}, a_1, a_2, m_1, m_2,\alpha \right) = \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\frac{a_1 f_1^2 \text{hr}_1^2 \text{hr}_2^2 m_2 \left(\frac{a_1 \text{hr}_1^2 m_2 \Sigma _2 \sqrt{\frac{G M_*}{a_1^3}}}{a_2}-\text{hr}_2^2 m_1 \Sigma _1 \sqrt{\frac{G M_*}{a_2^3}}\right)}{m_1 \left(a_2 m_1+2 a_1 m_2\right) \left(\text{hr}_1^4 \Sigma _2 f_{2 p}^2 \sqrt{\frac{G M_*}{a_1^3}}+4 f_1^2 \text{hr}_2^4 \Sigma _1 \sqrt{\frac{G M_*}{a_2^3}}\right)}}$$

In terms of $\alpha \equiv \frac{a_1}{a_2}$

**Edit**:

I try writing:

$$\text{e1eq}=\text{FullSimplify}\left[\sqrt{\frac{\frac{\tau _{e,1}}{\tau _{a,2}}-\frac{\tau _{e,1}}{\tau _{a,1}}}{2 (q+1) \left(\frac{m_1 q}{(q+1) \left(\alpha  m_2\right)}+1\right) \left(\frac{m_1 \left(\frac{q}{q+1}\right)^2 \left(\frac{f_{2 p}}{f_1}\right){}^2 \tau _{e,1}}{\left(\alpha  m_2\right) \tau _{e,2}}+1\right)}}\right]$$

and I get

$$\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\frac{\alpha ^2 f_1^2 \text{hr}_1^2 \text{hr}_2^2 m_2 \left(a_1 a_2^2 \text{hr}_1^2 m_2 \Sigma _2 \sqrt{\frac{G M_*}{a_1^3}} \sqrt{\frac{G M_*}{a_2^3}}-G \text{hr}_2^2 m_1 M_* \Sigma _1\right)}{m_1 \left(2 \alpha  m_2+m_1\right) \left(a_1 a_2^2 \text{hr}_1^4 \Sigma _2 f_{2 p}^2 \sqrt{\frac{G M_*}{a_1^3}} \sqrt{\frac{G M_*}{a_2^3}}+4 \alpha  f_1^2 G \text{hr}_2^4 M_* \Sigma _1\right)}}$$

which is correct, but then I run

`e1eq /. (Subscript[a, 1]/Subscript[a, 2]) -> \[Alpha]`

I end getting

$$\sqrt{2} \sqrt{\frac{\alpha ^2 f_1^2 \text{hr}_1^2 \text{hr}_2^2 m_2 \left(a_1 a_2^2 \text{hr}_1^2 m_2 \Sigma _2 \sqrt{\frac{G M_*}{a_1^3}} \sqrt{\frac{G M_*}{a_2^3}}-G \text{hr}_2^2 m_1 M_* \Sigma _1\right)}{m_1 \left(2 \alpha  m_2+m_1\right) \left(a_1 a_2^2 \text{hr}_1^4 \Sigma _2 f_{2 p}^2 \sqrt{\frac{G M_*}{a_1^3}} \sqrt{\frac{G M_*}{a_2^3}}+4 \alpha  f_1^2 G \text{hr}_2^4 M_* \Sigma _1\right)}}$$

which is the same

Comment: why can't you just use `expr /. (x2*x3) -> x4` ?  Or you can use `Simplify` with a side relation, as in  `expr = x1 + x2*x3; Simplify[expr, {x4 == x2*x3}]`  why is this not possible in your case? As for the function definition, well, this is just standard, is it not? And better use `:=` for definition and not `=`

Comment: I do not exactly know why expr /. (a1/a2)-> alpha is not working. I'm just defining the expresion and then trying to Simplify terms

Comment: Try ` expr /. (a1)-> alpha*a2`.  `ReplaceAll` (`./`) performs pattern-matching substitution, not algebraic substitution. To use it for algebraic substitutions, it's usually best to have a simple variable on the left-hand side of `->`.

Comment: `e1eq /. (Subscript[a, 1]/Subscript[a, 2]) -> \[Alpha]`  I do not see anywhere in `e1eq` expression $\frac{a_1}{a_2}$  Where do you see this? And to make sure you do the correct replacement, need to look at `FullForm` which is what Mathematica uses internally, not what shows on the screen.

Comment: You can do something like `Eliminate[y1 == x1 + x2*x3 && x4 == x2*x3, {x2}]`